# How i can get post data from database when i am getting post id from url in wordpress

Tags: php, html, get-posts

I am getting post id from url like this

```
https://www.example.com/download/?id=241
```

and in base of this id i want to get post data from db but it is getting nothing i tried this code

```
  <?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'category_name'          => 'download',
    'showposts'              => '1',
    'post_id'    => $id,
  'post_type' => 'page'
);

// The Query
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
//print_r($my_query);
  if ($my_query->have_posts() ) : while ($my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();  // Start the loop
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, true);
?>

                                 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $thumb_url[0]; ?>"  />
                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                    <time>تاريخ النشر: <?php the_time('l, F j, Y'); ?></time>
                                </a>                                    

            <?php
               endwhile; endif;// End the Loop and Check for Posts
               wp_reset_query(); // Reset the loop
             ?>
```

So i want to get the data by using the `id` i am getting through url. So please tell me what can i do with my code

Answer (score 1):

You may use $_GET parameter to get the id.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Or try this:

```
global $post;
echo $post->ID;
```

But it seems you have a problem in the args array. when you know the exact id of requested post you don't need to use it like that. you can use this instead:

```
get_post($id);
```

And then you do not need to loop through because you have one post to show.

Comment: I am using this sorry i forget to add this in my question i want to get data

Comment: you have put it outside of the <?php ... ?>.

Comment: No it is inside in my file i just paste it here outside

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = $_GET['id']; // get the ID from the URL

$post_data = get_post($id); // get post object
```

Then you get the post in `$post_data`. Simply check with:

```
var_dump($post_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working for a couple reasons.

1. You are trying to query the ID of a page and are specify a category taxonomy. Pages don't have categories associated with them normally.
2. The download is likely it's own post type so you'll want to specify that instead of "page"

Change your query args to the following and that *should* do the trick (based on the info that I have).

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'          => 'download', //use post_type instead since downloads is a post type not a taxonomy 
    'posts_per_page'              => '1',
    'post_id'    => $id,
);
```